# Get Facebook Picture in Cocos2d-iphone V3

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to get the profile picture from Facebook, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage stringByStandardizingPath]:
```

This is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=square", userid]];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 //convert UIImage to CCSprite
 CCTexture *texture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:image];
 CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
 sprite.position = ccp(winWidth*.5, winHeight*.5);
```

The error occurs in the UIImage *image line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your url **userid** is not valid so that this type of error is got. You have to enter Your userid to get picture.

Enter your userid thats got when you are login.

**My userid :**  100002026455444

**Url**  : http://graph.facebook.com/100002026455444/picture?type=square

Now run that URL after enter your userid. you got Your picture.

Code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=square",userid]];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 //convert UIImage to CCSprite
 CCTexture *texture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:image];
 CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
 sprite.position = ccp(winWidth*.5, winHeight*.5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just used userdid in my question as an example. But the error is still happening, even when I change userid for a real userid.

Answer (score 1):

If you open [the URL in a browser](http://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture?type=square) you'll see this isn't a valid image URL. Instead it POSTs an error response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: userid",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

To get profile pictures from Facebook you'll have to work with the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/). The user needs to give your app permission to access her profile pictures too.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just used userdid in my question as an example. But the error is still happening, even when I change userid for a real userid.

Comment: That's because you need permission from the user.